# NextJS + NextAuth - Checking subscription status of Customer

Tags: reactjs, session, next.js, subscription, next-auth

I have developed a shopping application using NextJS and uses NextAuth for authentication. Am using the `CredentialsProvider` for the custom authentication. Everything works fine. And on successful authentication, am storing the `customer_id` and `name` in the session.

Problem that am facing is, right now we are allowing customer to subscribe to our products (displayed inside our NextJS app) by paying an amount. So when the payment is successful, I will be storing a `is_subscribed` field as `true` in the database for that particular Customer. So for the client side displaying part, should I store this field value in the session?

The downside that I found is, if the subscription is cancelled, the Customer session needs to be updated as well. Btw am using JWT in the NextAuth for session storage. So the expiry of the token was set to 7 days by default. Hence, for already logged in Customers, the token won't be updated until 7 days.

How can this scenario be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

in scenarios like this you need to rely on server data as source of truth, you can still keep something on the session for the sake of UI, but whenever the user needs to make request or even you can set periodic / interval calls to your API to check for the subscription state if its true then you can proceed the user to make the change.

Comment: Thanks. What do you suggest for periodic check and storage? Using Context and SWR?

Comment: @VppMan there is nothing specific comes to my mind, I've done before using wrapper around axios call to do a check request before each api call to server,  for periodic calls you can setup a simple useEffect in a component and make calls with interval (don't forget to clear the interval on useEffect return)